# Alignment in C and division address variable

Tags: c, clang

Can someone explain to me what is the alignment in C.
I'm beginner in C and I can't completely know how to use it.

```
main(){
  int i1 = 1, i2 = -1;
  unsigned int ui1 = 1, ui2 = -1;
  long l1 = 2, l2 = -2;
  unsigned long ul1 = 2, ul2 = -2;
  float f1 = 2.5;
  double d1 = 2.5;
  char c = 'A';
}
```

I have to check whether addresses of individual variables in the program code enclosed are divisible by: 2, 4 and 8.

**How can this be related to the size of the variable and the alignment?**

I will be grateful for the logical explanation.

Extra code (transcribed from a comment):

```
if( *w_i1 % 2 == 0 )
{
    printf("Address of i1 divisible by 2\n");
}
else
    printf("No by 2\n");
if( *w_i1 % 4 == 0 )
{
    printf( "Address of i1 divisible by 4\n" );
}
else
    printf("No by 4\n");
if( *w_i1 % 8 == 0 )
{
    printf( "Address of i1 divisible by 8\n" );
}
else
    printf("No by 8\n");
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment

Comment: Data alignment is a somewhat advanced topic that's not really important for beginner programs.  But it sounds like you don't really need to learn (yet) about *why* variables are aligned the way they are; you just need to check whether an address is divisible by a number.

Comment: There is no standard/portable way to do this. And this is no valid C code, don't ignore warnings!

Comment: Note that the address of `c` is quite likely to be divisible by 8.  However, if you also have `char c0 = 'A', c1 = 'B', c2 = 'd', c3 = 'h';` then it is likely that some of those will not be aligned on a multiple of 2 (they'll be at odd addresses), let alone a multiple of 8.

Comment: The code from your comment, now transcribed into the question (where you should have put it in the first place), isn't compilable with the framework given.  You'd need `int *p_i1 = &i1; int **w_i1 = &p_i1;` for the `*w_i1` notation in the code to make much sense (and it wouldn't make much sense even so).  You probably need to use type `uintptr_t` (from `<inttypes.h>` since you'll want to format it with `PRIxPTR` too) to store the address, and pass the address (a `void *`) and variable name to a function that analyzes the address. It's worth doing the tests in order 8, 4, 2 and printing once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple way to do what you describe is to use the address opertor, (as you have commented) and casting:

```
int main(void){

    int a;//create the variable
    int *pA;//create a pointer

    pA = &a;//use the pointer to get the variable's address
    //  cast to allow test
    (((uintptr_t)pA%2)==0) ? printf("even\n") : printf("odd\n");//#include <stdint.h> 
    //(((unsigned int)pA%2)==0) ? printf("even\n") : printf("odd\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Note use of `uintptr_t`.  Per @Jonathan Leffler's  comment, this cast is large enough to contain a 64bit address, where `unsigned int`, although satisfies compile without errors, is not big enough to contain complete address.

Comment: I think you'd do better using `uintptr_t` from `<stdint.h>` or `<inttypes.h>` (and `PRIxPTR` and friends from `<inttypes.h>`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - please explain.

Comment: On my machine (64-bit), `unsigned int` isn't big enough to hold a complete address.  Granted, the low order 32-bits will tell you the alignment, but it feels uncomfortable to me using an not-wholly-appropriate type in the cast.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Thanks for explanation. It make sense, although odd my compiler did not squeak at all when I used `unsigned int`.

Comment: Which compiler, and which compilation options?  You might be 'OK' because the cast tells the compiler "I know what I'm doing" — and the compiler might even trust you on that.  When I compile with `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wold-style-definition -c up43.c`, I get errors (warnings if you don't make all warnings into errors) like
`up43.c: In function ‘main’:` and
`up43.c:8:7: error: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Werror=pointer-to-int-cast]` and
`(((unsigned int)pA%2)==0) ? printf("even\n") : printf("odd\n");`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - I am using (as I do most often do) a National Instruments implementation of ANSI C, LabWindows/CVI version 2015.  It is common for me to run into significant behavioral differences between this compiler, and my GCC implementation in Code Blocks.  Given your comments, when I can look at this again, I will run these variations on my GCC compiler (next time I can get to it) so I can see what you are seeing.  Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144209/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-ryyker).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Using `gcc --version` returns `gcc (tdm-1) 4.7.1`. and for the line: `(((unsigned int)pA%2)==0) ? printf("even\n") : printf("odd\n");`, and with with compiler settings: `mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -Wredundant-decls -Wunreachable-code -pedantic -Wextra -Wall -g -Wmain -Wall  -c main.c`  I get only `C++ style comments` warnings.  Is it possible that the differences are because I am running on Windows.  and (I assume) you are running Linux?

Comment: I'm primarily running on a Mac with macOS Sierra 10.12.4.  Yes, it is possible that it is due to platform differences; it is also possible that it is due to different versions of GCC.  I'm using 7.1.0 on the Mac, but I have some earlier versions, too. GCC 4.8.1 is still installed (that's the oldest version, though), and it gives me the same error as 7.1.0 does.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Well, I will keep playing with it.  I am still very new to using GCC, and to the Code::Blocks IDE.  I could very well be missing something.  I could not even find a warning option for requiring prototypes in this environment, where you clearly have that option: `-Wstrict-prototypes`  Anyway, thank you for your original comment.  I would not have known about the issue otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

First do this:

```
printf( "var %s is %d wide at %x\n", "i1", sizeof( i1 ), &i1 );
```

For each variable. Now you have printed the name %s, how many bytes it uses %d and the hexadecimal address %x of the variables. The next step is left for the student to answer. ;-) Hint: do the math in the code, not on a calculator.

Note that %x might need to be different depending on your compiler, check the documentation for printf on your system.

CPUs access data in chunks, aka a collection of bits. Specifically 1, 2, 4 bytes and so on. Some operations are faster when the variables are aligned to particular values, normally floating point. This may not be a strict requirement on modern CPUs. If it is, the compiler should make the adjustment itself.

Comment: `%x` for pointers is always wrong; use `%p` (casting `&i1` to `void *`).

Comment: `%p` is format specifier for addresses.